# global variable scope using javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Please forgive the following elementary question, as I am very rusty on javascript.  When I use the following code it works as expected, returning "Ford":

```
 var mysym = "Ford";
        function getName() {
            return "Ford";
        }
```

However, when I call the following, it does not work okay:

```
var myname = "Ford";
        function getName() {
           return myname;
    }
```

Edit:

The function is actually called from within a script that creates a widget, so maybe there is a timing issue...

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 var myname = "Ford";
        function getName() {
           return myname;
    }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="widget-container">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.yahoo.com/~/widget.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new getData.widget(
  {
  "width": 375,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": getName(),
  "locale": "en"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- Widget END -->
</body>
</html>
```

What is the proper way to store a value in a global variable?

Comment: This should work fine. Please give a minimal example so we can see the problem (and describe what exactly the problem is, just "does not work okay" is not enough).

Comment: OK. Maybe the issue is that the function is called from within another script belonging to a widget. I'll show that code too

Comment: Unless the *`https://s3.yahoo.com/~/widget.js`* script will overwrite the `myname` value, no, there won't be a difference between your `getName` function doing `return "Ford";` and `return myname;`.